# Sequentially compact metric space is totally bounded.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I want to prove this: " If for any sequence $(x_n)$ from a metric space $(E,d)$ we can extract a convergent subsequence then for any  $r>0$, we can cover $E$ by a finite number of open balls of radius $r$"

I star by the construction of the sequence

Let $x_0\in E$.

If $E=B(x_0,r)$ then we are done.

If not, there exists an $x_1\in E$ such that $x_1\notin B(x_0,r)$. If $E=B(x_0,r)\cup B(x_1,r)$ we are done.

If not .... there exists $x_n\in E$ but $$x_n\notin B(x_0,r)\cup \ldots\cup B(x_{n-1},r)$$

Then there exists a sequence  $(x_n)\in E$ such that $d(x_n,x_{n-1})>r,\, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*$, but how to continue ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The constructive condition $x_n\notin \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} B(x_i,r)$ doesn't just imply that $d(x_n,x_{n-1})\ge r$ for all $n>0$, but moreso that $d(x_n,x_m)\ge r$ for all $n>m$ (and thus for all $n\ne m$). Therefore, this sequence has no Cauchy subsequences, because $\inf\limits_{n\ne m} d(x_n,x_m)\ge r$.

Comment: and so it has not  a convergent subsequence, so we can't cover E ? I don't understand how to conclude?? @Saucy

Comment: Correct.  "No Cauchiness" implies implies no convergence.

Comment: and then this is a contradiction or what ? I don't understand how to conclude @avs

Comment: It's the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of what you are trying to prove: "If we can't cover $E$ with finitely many $r$-balls, then not every sequence will have a convergent subsequence."

Comment: @Vrouvrou. If $S=(x_{n(i)})_{i\in \Bbb N}$ is  any sub-sequence of $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ then $S$ is not Cauchy (because $i\ne j\implies d(x_{n(i)},x_{n(j)})> r)$ so $S$ certainly cannot be convergent